# cantools Error: ARXML: "File contains multiple elements with path ..."

Tags: python, can-bus

How can I suppress/ avoid/ skip the Error:

cantools.database.UnsupportedDatabaseFormatError: ARXML: "File contains multiple elements with path X"

X stands for actual path.

while running this code:

```
import cantools
arxml_path = "test.arxml"
arxml = cantools.db.load_file(arxml_path)
```

Why is it a problem, that multiple elements with the same path exist?
Can I edit the arxml file without altering its functionality?

Note: I did not create the arxml file and unfortunately can't share it.
Maybe someone has a hint.